# How to make Scalacheck arbString generate only readable Strings?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

Postgres doesn't accept all kind of symbols that Scalacheck arbString generates. Is there a way to generate human readable strings with Scalacheck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [the Gen object](https://www.scalacheck.org/files/scalacheck_2.11-1.13.0-api/index.html#org.scalacheck.Gen$) you can see a few generators, including `alphaChar` and `identifier`.

```
scala> import org.scalacheck.Gen._
import org.scalacheck.Gen._

scala> identifier.sample
res0: Option[String] = Some(vxlgvihQeknhe4PolpsJas1s0gx3dmci7z9i2pkYlxhO2vdrkqpspcaUmzrxnnb)

scala> alphaChar.sample
res1: Option[Char] = Some(f)

scala> listOf(alphaChar).sample
res2: Option[List[Char]] = Some(List(g, n, x, Y, h, a, c, e, a, j, B, d, m, a, r, r, Z, a, z, G, e, i, i, v, n, Z, x, z, t))

scala> listOf(alphaChar).map(_.mkString).sample
res3: Option[String] = Some(oupwJfqmmqebcsqbtRxzmgnJvdjzskywZiwsqnkzXttLqydbaahsfrjqdyyHhdaNpinvnxinhxhjyzvehKmbuejaeozytjyoyvb)
```

Comment: Thak you! Exactly what I want!

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by adding a case class `ReadableChar(c: Char)`, and defining an instance of arbitrary for it. Maybe something like

```
case class ReadableChar(c: Char)
implicit val arbReadable: Arbitrary[ReadableChar] = Arbitrary {
  val legalChars = Range('a', 'z').map(_.toChar)
  for {
    c <- Gen.oneOf(legalChars)
  } yield ReadableChar(c)
}
```

Then you can use the instance for `Arbitrary[Array[ReadableChar]]` to generate an array of readable chars, turn it into a string via `.map(_.c).toString`.

This works if you want to define "human readable strings" by the chars they are allowed to contain. If you need additional restrictions you can write a second case class `ReadableString(s: String)` and define an instance of `Arbitrary` for it, too.